# Selenium inserting <br> tags

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying out selenium at the moment and am using it to insert text into fields that are saved into a MySQL db. However, it seems to be adding a `<br>` tag at the end of the string.

For example, my line:

```
driver.find_element_by_id("griddescription").send_keys("Add item test Desc")
```

adds `Add item test Desc<br>` into the database.

Any ideas?

ANSWER:

I had forgotten to use the .clear() command first so the `<br>` tags were already there to begin with.

Comment: `send_keys` doesn't automatically append new line.. Are you sure this is not happening from somewhere else?

Comment: Thank you @MarounMaroun, you gave me the right idea;) I wasn't .clear()-ing the field before I inserted the text so the data was going in after the already present <br>

Comment: You can post an answer to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't .clear()-ing the field before I inserted the text so the data was going in after the already present